# Safe, Cross-platform way of running gcc within a program

Tags: c#, c++, gcc, mono

I am making a game engine editor and I would like the user to be able to build the game from within the editor. To do this they obviously need to run a compiler, such as gcc, with some flags.

Considering the editor is written in C# and is cross-platform (using Mono) what is a good way to run gcc from within the program?

I have heard of `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start();` but does this work in mono and is somewhat cross platform? Can you add flags with it?

EDIT: The actual game (not the editor) is written in c++ and requires gcc.

Comment: You plan on your users writing in something like C or C++ so it is compiled with gcc? If you plan on letting them use C# you dont need gcc.

Comment: Sorry yes the game's code is written in c++ just not the editor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Process class **is** cross-platform, yes.

You may want to look on how the C/C++ binding of MonoDevelop calls the compiler behind the scenes. The sources are [here](https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/tree/master/main/src/addins/CBinding)

Comment: Can you add flags to the call?

Comment: If you mean "arguments", then yes.